# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object(Algorithmic Change Required)

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, overriding

I am learning about Class Inheritance and overriding methods in python. To implement my learning, I wrote this code to let me better understand how Inheritance and Overriding works. But as I ran the code, I faced this error
"RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object"

I have tried to increase the recursion limit to 10000, but doing so, Python interpreter stopped working in my local machine. Can anyone help me with how I can overcome the error to have my expected output?
As I am new to the community, I may lack the appropriate presentation of the problem. Feel free to ask for more detailed information about the problem.

```
# Increasing Recursion Limit  
import sys  
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)


import random
# Parent Class

class Unique_id_creator():  
    def __init__(self, birthdate, birthmonth, birthyear):  
        self.date = birthdate  
        self.month = birthmonth  
        self.year = birthyear  

    def random_digits(self):
        last_two_digits = random.randrange(10, 99)
        return self.random_digits()

    def unique_id(self):
        id = int(self.date + self.month + self.year + self.random_digits())
        return self.unique_id()

# Child Class
class Unique_id_distributer(Unique_id_creator):  
    def __init__(self, name, birthdate, birthmonth, birthyear):  
        Unique_id_creator.__init__(self, birthdate, birthmonth, birthyear)  
        self.name = name  

    def unique_id(self):
        Unique_id_creator.unique_id(self)
        return "Dear "+ str(self.name) + ", Your Unique Id is: "+ str(self.unique_id())

citizen1 = Unique_id_distributer("hasan", "01", "11", "2000")  
print(citizen1.unique_id())
```

```
# Output Window
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line `return self.random_digits()` and this line `return self.unique_id()` are infinite recursive loops.

I assume what you intended to return was `last_two_digits` and `id`.

When you return a function call, that function has to execute to return the result of its call. Since you are calling the function you are executing it continues calling itself forever.

## Corrected code

```
# Increasing Recursion Limit
import sys  
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)


import random
# Parent Class
class Unique_id_creator:  
    def __init__(self, birthdate, birthmonth, birthyear):  
        self.date = birthdate  
        self.month = birthmonth  
        self.year = birthyear  

    def random_digits(self):
        last_two_digits = random.randrange(10, 99)
        # convert to a string since you are concatenating the result
        return str(last_two_digits)

    def unique_id(self):
        id = int(self.date + self.month + self.year + self.random_digits())
        return id

# Child Class
class Unique_id_distributer(Unique_id_creator):  
    def __init__(self, name, birthdate, birthmonth, birthyear):  
        Unique_id_creator.__init__(self, birthdate, birthmonth, birthyear)  
        self.name = name  

    def unique_id(self):
        id = Unique_id_creator.unique_id(self)
        return "Dear "+ str(self.name) + ", Your Unique Id is: "+ str(id)

citizen1 = Unique_id_distributer("hasan", "01", "11", "2000")  
print(citizen1.unique_id())
```

Additionally, you can eliminate the full call of your parent class by using `super()`.

## Child class example

```
# Child Class
class Unique_id_distributer(Unique_id_creator):  
    def __init__(self, name, birthdate, birthmonth, birthyear):  
        super().__init__(birthdate, birthmonth, birthyear)  
        self.name = name  

    def unique_id(self):
        id = super().unique_id()
        return "Dear "+ str(self.name) + ", Your Unique Id is: "+ str(id)
```

Comment: Your specific solution solved my confusion. Thanks a lot for your appreciation @Axe319