# Calling Grandfather class method results in RecursionError (maximum recursion depth exceeded)

Tags: python, recursion, inheritance

Im trying to call a grandfather method and getting the following error (RecursionError):

```
class GrandParent:
    def get_data(self):
        return 5


class Parent(GrandParent):
    def get_data(self):
        return super(self.__class__, self).get_data()


class Child(Parent):
    def get_other_data(self):
        d = self.get_data()
        print(d)
        return d


demo = Child()
res = demo.get_other_data()
print('done')
```

And i'm getting the following error:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Why is that?

I tried to look at this one: [RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object(Algorithmic Change Required)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63796009/recursionerror-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded-while-calling-a-python-objecta) but it seems like we shouldn't have any recursion issues.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self` is dynamicly binded, meaning it has the type of the actual created object, in this case `Child`.

Here is what happens in the case above:

```
class Parent(GrandParent):
    def get_data(self):
        return super(self.__class__, self).get_data()
```

evaluates to

```
class Parent(GrandParent):
    def get_data(self):
        return super(Child, self).get_data()
```

which is

```
class Parent(GrandParent):
    def get_data(self):
        return Parent.get_data(self)
```

You can now see why this is an endless recursion.

---

Python 2.7 best practice:

```
class Parent(GrandParent):
    def get_data(self):
        return super(Parent, self).get_data()
```

Python 3+:

```
class Parent(GrandParent):
    def get_data(self):
        return super().get_data()
```